# Cannot access Build a User Interface in App Script Editor

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-editor

I don't know why the Build a User Interface in Google App Script Editor is disabled (greyed). How can to enable it?

Thanks

Comment: You might to add the **google-apps-script-editor** tag to your question.

Answer (score 4):

Try saving the script from the script editor, giving the project a name, and then see if it works for you.